# RegEx to match specific words unless it's the last word in a sentence (titleize)

Tags: php, regex

i'm capitalizing all words, and then lowercasing words like **a**, **of**, **and**.
the first and last words should remain capitalized.
i've tried using `\s` instead of \b, and that caused some strange issues.
i've also tried `[^$]` but that doesn't seem to mean "not end of string"

```
function titleize($string){
  return ucfirst(
     preg_replace("/\b(A|Of|An|At|The|With|In|To|And|But|Is|For)\b/uie",
     "strtolower('$1')", 
     ucwords($string))
  );
}
```

this is the only failing test i'm trying to fix. the "in" at the end should remain capitalized.

```
titleize("gotta give up, gotta give in");
//Gotta Give Up, Gotta Give In
```

these tests pass:

```
titleize('if i told you this was killing me, would you stop?');
//If I Told You This Was Killing Me, Would You Stop?

titleize("we're at the top of the world (to the simple two)");
//We're at the Top of the World (to the Simple Two)

titleize("and keep reaching for those stars");
//And Keep Reaching for Those Stars
```

Comment: if you replace `inflector::humanize($string)` with `$string` everything works fine

Comment: sorry, that humanize is just replacing underscores, i'll get rid of it to simplify things. when running titleize('gotta give up, gotta give in'); that "in" at the end becomes lowercase, i'm looking for a solution to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/\b(A|Of|An|At|The|With|In|To|And|But|Is|For)(?!$)\b/uie
```

The negative lookahead `(?!$)` excludes matches where a endofline follows.

Answer (score 1):

You apply `ucwords()` before sending the string to the regex-replace, and then again `ucfirst` after returning from regex (for words appearing at the start of the string). This can be shortened by the **convention** that every word at the start and at the end of your string **is not surrounded by whitespaces**. Using this convention, we can use a regex like `'/(?<=\s)( ... )(?=\s)/'`. This will simplify your function somehow:

```
function titleize2($str) {
 $NoUc = Array('A','Of','An','At','The','With','In','To','And','But','Is','For');
 $reg = '/(?<=\s)('      # set lowercase only if surrounded by whitespace
      . join('|', $NoUc) # add OR'ed list of words
      . ')(?=\s)/e';     # set regex-eval mode
 return preg_replace( $reg, 'strtolower("\\1")', ucwords($str) );
}
```

If tested with:

```
...
$Strings = Array('gotta give up, gotta give in',
                 'if i told you this was killing me, would you stop?',
                 'we\'re at the top of the world (to the simple two)',
                 'and keep reaching for those stars');

foreach ($Strings as $s)
   print titleize2($s) . "\n";
...
```

... this will return the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a negative lookahead for the end of line `(?!$)` should do what you want

```
function titleize($string){
  return ucfirst(
     preg_replace("/\b(A|Of|An|At|The|With|In|To|And|But|Is|For)\b(?!$)/uie",
     "strtolower('$1')", 
     ucwords(inflector::humanize($string)))
  );
}
```